# ruby code to download a file from url with basic authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and I am learning it.

I am looking to download a file from one url(eg: https://myurl.com/123/1.zip), with basic authentication. I tried to execute the following ruby script, from windows command prompt..

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://myurl.com/123/1.zip')


Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https', 
  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  request.basic_auth 'john@test.com', 'John123'

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object

  puts response

  puts response.body
end
```

When I executed the script, I see no errors but the file isn't downloaded. Could you please kindly correct my code

Comment: You are printing the response. Instead write it to a file. https://gist.github.com/wbinglee/6f8ed65dded41fb9ccb2

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
require 'open-uri'

File.open('/path/your.file', "wb") do |file|
    file.write open('https://myurl.com/123/1.zip', :http_basic_authentication => ['john@test.com', 'John123']).read
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Just make use of ruby's send_data method

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://myurl.com/123/1.zip')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https', 
  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  request.basic_auth 'john@test.com', 'John123'

  http.request(request) do |response|
    send_data(response.body, filename: 'set_filename.pdf')
  end
end
```

Comment: this gives an error `NoMethodError: undefined method `send_data'`